# Keep <input type="text" /> at 100% width from overflowing its container without HTML hacks and also making it still look like a textbox?

Tags: css, input, width

First off, I say "without HTML hacks" in the subject because I don't have enough room to put all of these hacks on a single line.

I came across these questions, but they do not serve my needs:

[CSS Input with width: 100% goes outside parent's bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907518/css-input-with-width-100-goes-outside-parents-bound)
[How to set the same width for HTML text input and drop down input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088279/how-to-set-the-same-width-for-html-text-input-and-drop-down-input)
[Can I stop 100% Width Text Boxes from extending beyond their containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628500/can-i-stop-100-width-text-boxes-from-extending-beyond-their-containers)

Here are some reasons why:

- I cannot use block elements
- The input must retain its bevel/inset style so that it looks like a textbox (the business will not like an inconspicuous rectangle with a 1px solid border around it)
- No CSS3 (some users are still on IE6 and IE7)
- I cannot go wrapping every single input on our company website with magical DIV elements.

I've discovered that the `<!DOCTYPE>` directive affects this overflow behavior on inputs.  Research has told me that, without this directive, the browser is in quirks mode.  I guess that's why, in quirks mode, inputs look... correct?  I don't get it.

At any rate, here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pJkGB/2/

In case of rot, here's the HTML in that fiddle:

```
<input id="txtwoo" style="width:300px" type="text" />
<br />
<select id="cbowoo" style="width:300px">
</select>
```

Notice how the textbox is wider than the dropdown.  I want the *outer bounds* of the textbox to match the exact same width of the dropdown right down to the pixel (outer bounds included any borders, margins, etc).  The dropdown must be left alone.  I do not want to wrap the input with any elements.  I want a style that I can apply directly to the text input itself that will keep it from extending past the set pixel width.  I want it to retain its bevel/inset style.

If this is impossible, your answer of "you cannot do this" will suffice as an answer.  Otherwise, please fiddle with my fiddle and let me know how I can get this to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using:

```
input{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

If you want to go nuts, you could even use the below to specifically zero-in on text boxes:

```
input[type=text]{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ABefs/)

Comment: Awesome, the first one works great!  Are there any caveats that I'd need to be aware of (eg, compatibility with older browsers, etc)?  I probably won't be able to use the second one, but it's good to know about.